# /Volumes/Macintosh HD is mounted multiple times

Tags: macos, catalina

/Volumes/Macintosh HD is mounted multiple times, what is happening here and I see files/folders within each folder

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD
```

Comment: `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is a symbolic link to `/`. See `ls -l /Volumes/`.

Comment: Why do I see so many of them, can I unlink it after the first level

Comment: @Rpj No, you cannot. It's only mounted once (at `/`), the rest are just other ways of reaching the same path. Since `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is a symlink to `/`, it's inevitable that `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD` will resolve to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` and then that will resolve to `/`. Similarly, `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD` resolves to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD`, which .... This may be a bit confusing, but, well, computers are like that sometimes.